# WP Elementor { "code": "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce"}

Tags: elementor

After 1 year, i tried to update a page in my website from WP-Elementor. First of all, i updated all my already installed plugins, i did a backup and when i tried to update my page, elementor stucks and in console appears

{
"code": "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce",
"message": "Cookie check failed",
"data": {
"status": 403
}
}
I added a cache plugin, i configured it to delete cache every 10 hours.
Do you have any idea how to solve this error?

I installed cache plugin and delete all cached files. Nothing changed.
Also, i updated all plugins.